# Entity class mapping in hibernate, complex relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, database-design, persistence

I have four classes (A, B, C, D) all connected by relationship. I am using hibernate to store them in mysql database.

Structure of classes

```
Class A {
    Integer id;           //primary key
    List<B> listOfB;      //one to many with B class, able to store order of B's

    //some other fields
}

/* This class can contain list of c, or list of d, or both.
 * need to keep order among c and d also if contains both list
 * for eg, B has list of c(c1, c2, c3) and D (d1, d2, d3)
 * order can be c1, d1, c2, d3, c3, d2
 */
Class B {
    Integer id;           //primary key
    List<C> listOfC;      //one to many with D class, able to store order of C's
    List<D> listOfD;      //one to many with C class, able to store order of D's

    //How to store order between list of c and list of d?       

     //some other field
}

Class C {
    Integer id;           //primary key
    List<D> listOfD;      //one to many with D class, able to store order of D's

     //some other field
}

Class D {
    Integer id;           //primary key
    String value;         //some value

}
```

Here relation between A and B is one to many, B to C is one to many, B to D is one to many, C to D is one to many.

List has been used just to keep track of order between objects. But I want also to keep track of order of list of c and d in B class.

```
B can have following steps:
 1. C1
 2. D1
 3. c2
 4. D2
```

With the current design I am not able to store the order between c and d.

please suggest some design. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inherit `C` and `D` from an abstract entity and use a single list in `B`.

The abstract entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discr")
public abstract class X {
    Integer id; 
    // ...
}
```

Then extend it:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("c")
public class C extends X {
    List<D> listOfD;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("d")
public class D extends X {
    String value;     
    // ...
}
```

and finally:

```
@Entity
public class B {
    Integer id;
    List<X> listOfX; // single list for C and D
}
```

Take a look at [inheritance stategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3356). In my example I'm using single table strategy.

Also take a look to [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)

Obviously you need to add relationship annotations.

Comment: but how hibernate will store them in db? The structure of C and D can be different

Comment: @Raj take a look at Hibernate documentation (link in the answer). You can have several tables (one for each type) or just a single table one with all the fields, plus a discriminator column.